# Python to validate CSV data

Tags: python, csv, validation

I have a simple CSV data file which has two rows Namely `Object_Id` and `VALUE` and each index of `Object ID` has a corresponding value for the same index in the other row (`VALUE`). My intent is to read those index and validate these data with expected data.

I am able to read the csv file but not sure how to validate the data. 
Here is a piece of the csv file:

```
Obj ID,    Value,    Time Stamp
13,    41.0,    2018-09-10 23:05:30
14,    14.0,    2018-09-10 23:05:20
13,    41.0,    2018-09-10 23:05:20
14,    14.0,    2018-09-10 23:05:09
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
import csv
with open('testoutfile1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
observed_output=[]
expected_output=[]
for row in reader:
    #print(';  '.join(row))
    observed_output = {row[0]:row[1]}
    print(observed_output)
expected_output= {'Obj ID': 'Value','13':'41.0', '14':'14.0'}
print(expected_output)

for key in expected_output:
    if key in observed_output:
            print (key)
            print (observed_output[key])
            print (expected_output [key])
        if (observed_output[key])== (expected_output [key]):
            print ("Test Passed")
        elif (observed_output[key])!= (expected_output [key]):
            print ("Test Failed")
```

And here is the output I receive which is surely missing to match the other entry/entries. Can you please comment?

```
{'Obj ID': 'Value'}
{'13': '41.0'}
{'14': '14.0'}
{'13': '41.0'}
{'14': '14.0'}
{'Obj ID': 'Value', '13': '41.0', '14': '14.0'}
14
14.0
14.0
Test Passed
```

Comment: Where does the validation data come from? Another csv?

Comment: Validation data is coming from a desktop app GUI (visual) where the actual logic operations are running. I have to validate the data what I see from the output of some logic operations with the data in the csv file.

Comment: Stack Overflow can help you solve specific questions based on work you have already done and specific problem you are haced with, not a whole project. Best steps are writing pseudocode for your tasks, show your progress and put some runnable code. Otherwise what you ate asking is 'code it for me', which should be directed to upwork or freelancer.com

Comment: Here is the code I am trying:    import csv
with open('testoutfile1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    Object_ID = []
    Observed_Output = []
    Expected_Output = []
    for row in reader:
        print(';  '.join(row))
        Object_ID.append(row[0])
        Observed_Output.append(row[1])

Comment: Tried to edit the code in here but could not get the right format..hope it is still readable..

Comment: That is a great start, put it your question along with some the data too. It best case there is some code one can cut and run locally  and replicate your problem. This is actually next question what is wrong with your original solution: your data structure is actually pairs from row 1 and row2? Is this correct? Are you trying to validate these pairs with just second row? Is this the case? With a bit if data in your code we would have seen right away.

Comment: Maybe put a little piece of csv into the question for clarity?

Comment: Actually the validation should take place as a pair as well. Because each specific object ID has its corresponding value and both needs to be validated as a pair.

Comment: You seem to be able to ignore the timestamp. If true, you can read the csv file as list  id: value dictionaries and check the values by same id, it it the same in GUI. Otherwuse you can demonsrate what does your expected value data structure look like.

Comment: Based on your advice, I have now coded as above and got the mentioned output. Two things I still don't get right: 1) when I convert the csv to dictionary (observed_output), it gets into row format whereas my expected_output dictionary is in column format. Does it make any problem while matching the pair {keys, values}? 2) After all these, it still does not get the other entry key [13], rather it found only key [14]. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `expected_output` in my opinion should be a simpler dictionary

```
expected_output = {'13':'41.0', '14':'14.0'}
```

next you can proceed like this

```
data = open('...')
next(data) # skip headers
for line in data:
    id, val, *_ = [item.strip() for item in line.split(',')]
    if id in expected_output and val == expected_output[id]:
        # the observed output is the same as expected
        ...
    else:
        # observed is unexpected
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some fo this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import csv    

doc = """Obj ID,Value,Time Stamp
13,41.0,2018-09-10 23:05:30
14,14.0,2018-09-10 23:05:20
13,41.0,2018-09-10 23:05:20
14,14.0,2018-09-10 23:05:09"""

#replicate a data file
Path('temp.csv').write_text(doc)  


#read a csv to dicts
def read_dicts(filename, sep=",", names=['id', 'value', 'time']): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=sep, fieldnames=names)
        return [row for row in reader][1:]            
dicts = read_dicts('temp.csv')
# you can start checking *dicts* from here

# use pandas 
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', names = ['id', 'value', 'time'], header=0)
# this is not a great way to check (you loose information), but it seems what you ask for
assert df['value'].tolist() == [41.0, 14.0, 41.0, 14.0]

# if the data on objects does not change, check this way, write this to a fucntion
assert (df[df.id==13].value == 41).all()
assert (df[df.id==14].value == 14).all()

# you can replicate the above with a csv too.
```

To check properly you need to make explict your assumptions about data structure (do values change in time?) and adjust a check accordingly.